# Vision- grabbing source image uri in each AnnotateImageResponse from batch_annotate_images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, face-recognition, image-recognition, google-cloud-vision

Images are uploaded in google bucket. Code given below is running fine. It's in python3. I am trying to catch each image_uri for corresponding AnnotateImageResponse so that I can save responses in database with corresponding image uris. How can I grab input image_uri for each response? Because in each response, source image uri data not available. I may be wrong but I guess, while making requests in generate_request function, I may need to send image_uri as image_context, but not finding any good docs for that. please help.

*Image files uploaded in google buckets are*
'39149.7ae80cfb87bb228201e251f3e234ffde.jpg', 'anatomy_e.jpg'

```
def generate_request(input_image_uri):
    if isinstance(input_image_uri, six.binary_type):
        input_image_uri = input_image_uri.decode('utf-8')
    source = {'image_uri': input_image_uri}
    image = {'source': source}
    features = [{"type_": vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},{"type_": vision.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION},{"type_": vision.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION}]
    requests = {"image": image, "features": features}
    
   
    return requests


def sample_async_batch_annotate_images(input_uri):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    requests = [
        generate_request(input_uri.format(filename)) for filename in ['39149.7ae80cfb87bb228201e251f3e234ffde.jpg','anatomy_e.jpg',]
    ]
    # below response is A BatchAnnotateFilesResponse instance.     
    response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests=requests)
    for each in response.responses:
        #each response is AnnotateImageResponse instance
        print("each_response", each)
    
sample_async_batch_annotate_images('gs://imagevisiontest/{}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was a little bit confused on your `sample_async_batch_annotate_images` function since it was named asynchronous but you are not using the asynchronous method of Vision API. The response from batch_annotate_images does not return `context` that contains the source image_uri. Also the [image_context](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext) is only used to refine your image detection like providing language hints, telling the API to search for products, etc.

I suggest using the [asynchronous batch annotate method](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#vision_async_batch_annotate_images-python) of the API as it will include `context` which is seen at the end of the response along with the source image_uri. Also the response is saved in the `output_uri` specified in the code.

I processed [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqboL.jpg) and I renamed it to image_text.jpeg for testing on `batch_annotate_images` and `async_batch_annotate_images`:

Code snippet used for `batch_annotate_images`:

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1

def sample_batch_annotate_images(
    input_image_uri="gs://your_bucket_here/image_text.jpeg",
):
    client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    source = {"image_uri": input_image_uri}
    image = {"source": source}
    features = [
        {"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
        {"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES},
    ]

    requests = [{"image": image, "features": features}]

    response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests=requests)
    print(response)

sample_batch_annotate_images()
```

Response from `batch_annotate_images`:

```
responses {
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/02wzbmj"
    description: "Standing"
    score: 0.9516521096229553
    topicality: 0.9516521096229553
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/01mwkf"
    description: "Monochrome"
    score: 0.9407921433448792
    topicality: 0.9407921433448792
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/01lynh"
    description: "Stairs"
    score: 0.9399806261062622
    topicality: 0.9399806261062622
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/03scnj"
    description: "Line"
    score: 0.9328843951225281
    topicality: 0.9328843951225281
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/012yh1"
    description: "Style"
    score: 0.9320641756057739
    topicality: 0.9320641756057739
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/03d49p1"
    description: "Monochrome photography"
    score: 0.911144495010376
    topicality: 0.911144495010376
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/01g6gs"
    description: "Black-and-white"
    score: 0.9031684994697571
    topicality: 0.9031684994697571
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/019sc"
    description: "Black"
    score: 0.8788009881973267
    topicality: 0.8788009881973267
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/030zfn"
    description: "Parallel"
    score: 0.8722482919692993
    topicality: 0.8722482919692993
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/05wkw"
    description: "Photography"
    score: 0.8370979428291321
    topicality: 0.8370979428291321
  }
  image_properties_annotation {
    dominant_colors {
      colors {
        color {
          red: 195.0
          green: 195.0
          blue: 195.0
        }
        score: 0.4464040696620941
        pixel_fraction: 0.10618651658296585
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 117.0
          green: 117.0
          blue: 117.0
        }
        score: 0.16896472871303558
        pixel_fraction: 0.1623961180448532
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 13.0
          green: 13.0
          blue: 13.0
        }
        score: 0.12974770367145538
        pixel_fraction: 0.24307478964328766
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 162.0
          green: 162.0
          blue: 162.0
        }
        score: 0.11677403748035431
        pixel_fraction: 0.09510618448257446
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 89.0
          green: 89.0
          blue: 89.0
        }
        score: 0.08708541840314865
        pixel_fraction: 0.17659279704093933
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 225.0
          green: 225.0
          blue: 225.0
        }
        score: 0.05102387070655823
        pixel_fraction: 0.012119113467633724
      }
      colors {
        color {
          red: 64.0
          green: 64.0
          blue: 64.0
        }
        score: 1.7074732738819876e-07
        pixel_fraction: 0.2045244723558426
      }
    }
  }
  crop_hints_annotation {
    crop_hints {
      bounding_poly {
        vertices {
          x: 123
        }
        vertices {
          x: 226
        }
        vertices {
          x: 226
          y: 182
        }
        vertices {
          x: 123
          y: 182
        }
      }
      confidence: 0.4375000298023224
      importance_fraction: 0.794996440410614
    }
  }
}
```

Code snippet used for `async_batch_annotate_images` (got the code in [Vision API docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#vision_async_batch_annotate_images-python)):

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1

def sample_async_batch_annotate_images(
    input_image_uri="gs://your_bucket_here/image_text.jpeg",
    output_uri="gs://your_bucket_here/",
):
    """Perform async batch image annotation."""
    client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    source = {"image_uri": input_image_uri}
    image = {"source": source}
    features = [
        {"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
        {"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES},
    ]

    # Each requests element corresponds to a single image.  To annotate more
    # images, create a request element for each image and add it to
    # the array of requests
    requests = [{"image": image, "features": features}]
    gcs_destination = {"uri": output_uri}

    # The max number of responses to output in each JSON file
    batch_size = 2
    output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination,
                     "batch_size": batch_size}

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests=requests, output_config=output_config)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(90)

    # The output is written to GCS with the provided output_uri as prefix
    gcs_output_uri = response.output_config.gcs_destination.uri
    print("Output written to GCS with prefix: {}".format(gcs_output_uri))

sample_async_batch_annotate_images()
```

Response from `async_batch_annotate_images`:

```
{
  "responses":[
    {
      "labelAnnotations":[
        {
          "mid":"/m/02wzbmj",
          "description":"Standing",
          "score":0.9516521,
          "topicality":0.9516521
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/01mwkf",
          "description":"Monochrome",
          "score":0.94079214,
          "topicality":0.94079214
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/01lynh",
          "description":"Stairs",
          "score":0.9399806,
          "topicality":0.9399806
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/03scnj",
          "description":"Line",
          "score":0.9328844,
          "topicality":0.9328844
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/012yh1",
          "description":"Style",
          "score":0.9320642,
          "topicality":0.9320642
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/03d49p1",
          "description":"Monochrome photography",
          "score":0.9111445,
          "topicality":0.9111445
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/01g6gs",
          "description":"Black-and-white",
          "score":0.9031685,
          "topicality":0.9031685
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/019sc",
          "description":"Black",
          "score":0.878801,
          "topicality":0.878801
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/030zfn",
          "description":"Parallel",
          "score":0.8722483,
          "topicality":0.8722483
        },
        {
          "mid":"/m/05wkw",
          "description":"Photography",
          "score":0.83709794,
          "topicality":0.83709794
        }
      ],
      "imagePropertiesAnnotation":{
        "dominantColors":{
          "colors":[
            {
              "color":{
                "red":195,
                "green":195,
                "blue":195
              },
              "score":0.44640407,
              "pixelFraction":0.10618652
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":117,
                "green":117,
                "blue":117
              },
              "score":0.16896473,
              "pixelFraction":0.16239612
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":13,
                "green":13,
                "blue":13
              },
              "score":0.1297477,
              "pixelFraction":0.24307479
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":162,
                "green":162,
                "blue":162
              },
              "score":0.11677404,
              "pixelFraction":0.095106184
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":89,
                "green":89,
                "blue":89
              },
              "score":0.08708542,
              "pixelFraction":0.1765928
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":225,
                "green":225,
                "blue":225
              },
              "score":0.05102387,
              "pixelFraction":0.0121191135
            },
            {
              "color":{
                "red":64,
                "green":64,
                "blue":64
              },
              "score":1.7074733e-07,
              "pixelFraction":0.20452447
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "cropHintsAnnotation":{
        "cropHints":[
          {
            "boundingPoly":{
              "vertices":[
                {
                  "x":123
                },
                {
                  "x":226
                },
                {
                  "x":226,
                  "y":182
                },
                {
                  "x":123,
                  "y":182
                }
              ]
            },
            "confidence":0.43750003,
            "importanceFraction":0.79499644
          }
        ]
      },
      "context":{
        "uri":"gs://your_bucket_here/image_text.jpeg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Knowingly, not making call using async_batch_annotate_images because I did not want to store response in GCS bucket (output_uri) which is required. Thanks!

Comment: and for *sample_async_batch_annotate_images* function name thing, yes it should be named as *sample_batch_annotate_images* as it's not calling asynchronous batch annotate method.

Comment: For example, using  batch_annotate_images service with giving 5 image-requests sequentially, can we expect response in the same order requests are queued? Please let me know

Comment: Yes you can expect the response to be in the same order as your requests.